# Is it possible to put a ListView inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to put a `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. However, I am getting the following errors:

- The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
- error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element.

I don't understand why its not working since I am able to put 2 `FrameLayouts` inside a `LinearLayout`.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the `<RelativeLayout>` too early:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/> <- this is wrong
```

Remove the `/>` at the end, and just make it `>` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
If you have only ListView then you can achieved this way :

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/listview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:background="@drawable/background" />
```